# Can't register an custom Entity in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hello I have custom entity which has fields like name, description, date ant others, I created `EventRepository` and `EventServiceImpl`. Also i have a model `RegisterEvent`.

#### Event entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "events")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "games_at_event", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "games")
private List<String> games = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "event_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"))
private List<User> players;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String description;
private String date;
private User owner;
private String gamesToParse;
private String usersToParse;


public String getGamesToParse() {
    return gamesToParse;
}

public void setGamesToParse(String gamesToParse) {
    this.gamesToParse = gamesToParse;
}

public String getUsersToParse() {
    return usersToParse;
}

public void setUsersToParse(String usersToParse) {
    this.usersToParse = usersToParse;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public User getOwner(){
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(User owner){
    this.owner = owner;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(double latitude){
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude( double longitude){
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName( String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<String> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(List<String> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

public void setGames(String gamesData) {
    String[] array = gamesData.split(",");
    for (String g:array) {
        this.games.add(g);
    }
}

public List<User> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<User> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

}
```

#### EventRepository:

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    Event findOneByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
    List<Event> findAll();
}
```

#### EventServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private EventRepository eventRepository;

@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

public EventServiceImpl() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void register(RegistrationEvent registrationEvent) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName();

    Event event = this.modelMapper.map(registrationEvent, Event.class);
    event.setGames(registrationEvent.getGamesToParse());
    event.setDescription(registrationEvent.getDescription());
    event.setLatitude(registrationEvent.getLatitude());
    event.setLongitude(registrationEvent.getLongitude());
    event.setName`enter code here`(registrationEvent.getName());
    event.setPlayers(registrationEvent.getPlayers());
    event.setDate(registrationEvent.getDate());
    System.out.println(name);
    event.setOwner(this.userRepository.findOneByUsername(name));
    this.eventRepository.save(event);
}

}
```

#### RegisterEvent Model

```
public class RegistrationEvent {
@Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "Event name too short")
private String name;
private List<String> games = new ArrayList<>();
private List<User> players = new ArrayList<>();
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String description;
private User owner;
private String date;
private String gamesToParse;
private String usersToParse;

public String getGamesToParse() {
    return gamesToParse;
}

public void setGamesToParse(String gamesToParse) {
    this.gamesToParse = gamesToParse;
}

public String getUsersToParse() {
    return usersToParse;
}

public void setUsersToParse(String usersToParse) {
    this.usersToParse = usersToParse;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public List<User> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<User> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

public List<String> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(String gamesData) {
    String[] array = gamesData.split(",");
    for (String g:array) {
        this.games.add(g);
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

But when i Try to register event in my Html :

```
<div class="transbox4">

    <form method="post" th:object="${event}">
    <p align="center" class ="specialText">
        <span class="blue"> INFO </span>
    </p>
    <div align="center">
        <div id="info" class ="specialText">
            <span class="blue"> Event name*: </span><br>
            <input type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{name}" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> Games at the event*: </span><br>
            <input type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{gamesToParse}" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> Date*: </span><br>
            <input type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{date}" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> Player emails*: </span><br>
            <input type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{usersToParse}" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> Description: </span><br>
            <input type="textarea" class="input2" th:field="*{description}" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> latitude*: </span><br>
            <input id="mapEnd1" type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{latitude}" value="" /><br>

            <span class="blue"> longitude*: </span><br>
            <input id="mapEnd2" type="text" class="input2" th:field="*{longitude}" value="" /><br>
            <p class="smallInfo" align="center">fields with * must be filled!</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Field 'event_id' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1332) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.app.ServiceImpl.EventServiceImpl.register(EventServiceImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.app.Controllers.EventsController.registerEvent(EventsController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

And in the browser shows:
[image]

I don't know whats happening in the error says my id don't have a value but it does i generate it.

Comment: Can you also add your `User` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue and the error explains it clearly. The `event_id` has not its default value and you have to fix it on the database level.

```
ALTER TABLE events MODIFY COLUMN event_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Or set it as `null` by default in case `null` is allowed `SET DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: the question is about `event_id` not `entity_id`